How to change Oracle's Enterprise manager 12c runtime properties from a webservice call?
I work with Oracle SOA Suite (Oracle fusion middleware 12c and 11g), combined with weblogic 12c, Azure pipelines, git repository, and SOAtest from parasoft as testtool.
I want to be able to change service properties from my testtool on the run without having to redeploy services. And I would like to do this automised from my Azure pipelines.
I can access properties from Oracle' s Enterprise manager, in order to, for example, change a read-timeout for a service call to trigger that service' s error handling. However, I do not want to do this by hand, I want to write tests that do this automatically by using API calls.
I have heard of people using Oracles Locator API, but I cannot find any documentation.
Does anybody know how to change Enterprise manager runtime properties from a webservice call?
Every piece of information is welcome!
Cheers, Jesper

You can try with OEM Rest API:
Rest APIs are available 'only for Private cloud' to fetch resource allocations in OEM.
Refer below document for more details. Section 'Using the Cloud APIs'.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E73210_01/EMCLO/GUID-C0C2CE8B-3098-43AB-AC99-A2E4B9E974FC.htm#EMCLO999
For OEM 13.4 version, 'Execute SQL' is supported via REST API. You can now use HTTP-based REST endpoints to execute SQL commands and extract data.
Only below options are available via REST API to extract data.
The Oracle Management Repository (OMR)
A database target configured in Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) Cloud Control
Refer below document for more details. Section 'Executing SQL via REST API'.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/enterprise-manager/cloud-control/enterprise-manager-cloud-control/13.4/emadm/executing-sql-rest-api.html
The above document is updated as per following ERs.
ER 29726155 : Support Execute SQL via REST API
Documentation Bug 30669719 : new feature: new REST APIs for Execute SQL
Also note that some of the bugs related to above REST API features are fixed in RU12. So it is advisable to apply latest RU on OMS.
Refer below document for latest available OMS RUs.
Enterprise Manager 13.4 Main Release Update List (Includes Plug-ins) (Doc ID 2647078.2)
Modify an existing global target property
https://EM_HOST:8080/em/api/globalTargetProperties/{globalTargetPropertyID}
This api modifies an existing global target property identified by the given id.
Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/enterprise-manager/cloud-control/enterprise-manager-cloud-control/13.5/emrest/op-https-em_host-8080-em-api-globaltargetproperties-globaltargetpropertyid-patch.html
Hope it helps!

Thank you for the answer Eduardo. Its not exactly what i' m looking for, as we don' t have an oracle cloud installation, only on premise. But I think I have enough to work with!

Tks my friend!!
